# make button round with css

Tags: html, css

Please can any one help me with this code

```html
<button class="btn input-button"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="margin-left: 138px; background: #434190;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-lg" style="color: #ffff; margin-left: 4px;"></i></span></button>
```

Comment: You already got some answers here but next time it will be better to include some examples of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add border radius using css.

```html
<button class="btn input-button" style="border-radius:5px;"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="margin-left: 138px; background: #434190;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-lg" style="color: #ffff; margin-left: 4px;"></i></span></button>

<button class="btn input-button" style="border-radius:10px;"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="margin-left: 138px; background: #434190;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-lg" style="color: #ffff; margin-left: 4px;"></i></span></button>

<button class="btn input-button" style="border-radius:100%;"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="margin-left: 138px; background: #434190;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-lg" style="color: #ffff; margin-left: 4px;"></i></span></button>

<button class="btn input-button" style="border-radius:50%;"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="margin-left: 138px; background: #434190;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-lg" style="color: #ffff; margin-left: 4px;"></i></span></button>

<button class="btn input-button" style="border-radius:100px;"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="margin-left: 138px; background: #434190;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-lg" style="color: #ffff; margin-left: 4px;"></i></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```html
<button style='border-radius: 20px' class="btn input-button"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="margin-left: 138px; background: #434190;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-lg" style="color: #ffff; margin-left: 4px;"></i></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work,

```
<button style="border-radius: 50%" class="btn input-button"><span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="margin-left: 138px; background: #434190;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-lg" style="color: #ffff; margin-left: 4px;"></i></span></button>
```

You can check the following link for details: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_round_buttons.asp